# MFMailComposeViewController is not dismissing - Swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm currently trying to implement `MFMailComposeViewController`. Everything is working fine, except after sending an email or clicking cancel, the `MFMailComposeViewController` does not dismiss. I've looked at similar StackOverflow threads and attempted to implement those solutions, but they have not resolved my issue. I feel like the issue may not lie within the `func mailComposeController`, but within the rest of my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
   if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let vc = MFMailComposeViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.mailComposeDelegate = self
        vc.setSubject("Contact Us/Feedback")
        vc.setToRecipients(["test@gmail.com"])
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    else {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
                
        present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
        }

    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                               didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
      
        // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
     didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
```

To

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, 
     didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
```

Comment: Also, delete `vc.delegate = self`, as it does nothing.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have implemented this edit, however, it does not solve my issue. The MFMailComposeViewController still does not dismiss. I've also deleted vc.delegate = self    Thanks

Comment: Oh, and take that entire method, including both curly braces, cut it, and paste it at the top level of the class declaration. You've written it inside another method, where it can never be called.